# Any way to restrict properties which can be used in an odata filter?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

Does anyone know of a way to restrict the properties which can be used in an OData query?
The documentation shows how to implement a FilterQueryValidator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/odata-security

I can't find any documentation which describes how you'd actually use this validator.
Anyone else have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

When creating your EDM model, add a restriction to the property you don't want someone filtering on.

```cs
var employee = builder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employees").EntityType;
employee.Property(e => e.FirstName).IsNotFilterable();
```

There are similar methods to restrict expanding, sorting, counting, and navigating.

Answer (score -3):

You can use $select to allow the clients to select specific properties from the server:

```
$select=
```

Attach it to your url, like

```
http://****/odata/Customers?$select=property1,Property2.....
```

You can check the results:

[image]

More details, you can check this tutorial:

[$select Enhancement in ASP.NET Core OData](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/select-enhancement-in-asp-net-core-odata/)

Comment: OP is not asking how to use `$select`, but how to prevent users from using `$select` or possibly `$expand` or `$fitler` to access or operate on specific fields in the resource